# GridLayout with scaled images has huge row spacing

Tags: layout, qml

I have a simple "dialog" in qml where the user is supposed to select one image. Images are scaled-down and shown in a GridLayout inside ScrollView. Images should be 1/2 width of the scrollview, there will be descriptions next to it.

What I see is that the vertical spacing is huge and it does not change with resizing the window. It actually seems that the spacing corresponds to full-size (unscaled) images.

The issue changes when I set `Layout.preferredHeight: 100` (for example), but then again the spacing is there should the images be smaller than that, and don't grow beyond 100px in height. I would like to solve this without supposing any absolute sizes.

How to fix that?

[image: spacing issue]

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
ApplicationWindow{
    visible: true
    id: root
    width: 600
    height: 1200
    ScrollView {
        id: scroll
        anchors.fill: parent
        ListModel{
            id: demosModel
            ListElement{  src:"01.jpg"; }
            ListElement{  src:"02.jpg"; }
            ListElement{  src:"03.jpg"; }
            ListElement{  src:"04.jpg"; }
        }

        GridLayout{
            anchors.fill: parent
            columns: 1
            rowSpacing: 10
            Repeater{
                model: demosModel
                Image {
                    source: "assets/"+src;
                    Layout.preferredWidth: .5*scroll.width;
                    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Defining your Image this way `Image { source: src; sourceSize.width: .5 * scroll.width;  fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit; }` doesn't fix your problem?

Comment: It does :) How do you know this? I find the layouts, resizing etc something inherently arcane and I admire those who see the logic behind. Please re-post as answer so that I can accept :)

Comment: I often came across errors related to item sizes and layouts. I am finally beginning to understand how to address these issues but I do not understand them all the time. When I find the time to deepen the thing, I try to see in the source code of Qt, but it's not always easy... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example:

- `Image { source: "assets/"+src }` will use the real size of the images.
- `Layout.preferredWidth: .5*scroll.width` will limit the width of the area in which the image will be displayed. So the big images will be displayed with a width of 300px (.5*scroll.width) but will conserve their height.
- `fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit;` will scale the image uniformly to fit in the 300px. The proportions of the images are now visually OK **but** the value of the `height` property remains the same and this is this value which will be used by the layout.

So I think the solution is to force the width (the height will be recalculated) of the element via the `sourceSize` property:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow{
    id: root
    width: 600
    height: 1200
    visible: true

    ScrollView {
        id: scroll
        anchors.fill: parent

        ListModel{
            id: demosModel
            ListElement{  src:"01.jpg"; }
            ListElement{  src:"02.jpg"; }
            ListElement{  src:"03.jpg"; }
            ListElement{  src:"04.jpg"; }
        }

        GridLayout{
            anchors.fill: parent
            columns: 1
            rowSpacing: 10

            Repeater{
                model: demosModel

                Image {
                    source: "assets/" + src;
                    Layout.preferredWidth: .5 * scroll.width;

                    // Qt documentation: "If only one dimension of the size is set to greater
                    // than 0, the other dimension is set in proportion to preserve the
                    // source image's aspect ratio. (The fillMode is independent of this.)"
                    //      fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit;
                    sourceSize.width: Layout.preferredWidth
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. Thanks!